# React native error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.marketing.ViewIndexer.unschedule()' on a null object reference

Tags: javascript, react-native

I use react-native-facebook-account-kit library. The build is uploaded production. I get this error. But I don't know where the error

Error detail blow

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.abc.xyz/com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.marketing.ViewIndexer.unschedule()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:3914)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3880)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3854)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3828)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6530)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

react-native: 0.55.0

react-native-fbsdk: 0.8.0

react-native-facebook-account-kit: 0.10.1

Sorry, my English not good.
Thanks for read the post

Comment: For library issues like this, I always recommend looking at the issue tracker on the repo

Comment: @Kai: I posted it here when I studied this issue but not found root cause.